# Reset GDM to default Display  Manager

Tags: xubuntu, login-screen, gdm, slim

I'm currently running Xubuntu 10.04 LTS and wanted to try out the SLiM display manager on my system.

Well I installed it (from the synaptic package manager) and something really bad happened; I can't even get to the display manage anymore to log in.

When I boot up normally, it shows the Xubuntu logo, then shows this one underscore in the top-left corner of my screen.  I tried pressing "Alt+Ctrl+F1" to launch a virtual terminal but that didn't work.

I also tried to boot into recovery mode via GRUB.  When I got to the recovery screen, if I were to press any of the arrow keys, the screen would show the Xubuntu logo.  If I press the arrow key again, it would go back to the recovery screen, but it wouldn't move down an option.

It isn't too bad if I'll need to re-install Xubuntu (I backed up all my important data a day ago), but it would be a real pain in the but if I had to.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that maybe resetting GDM to the default WM might fix it, but you see, I can't even log in to try to edit the "/etc/X11/default-display-manager" file.

EDIT2;
I decided just to bite the bullet and re-install/update Xubuntu.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Can you anyway get the terminal or CLI prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a text-based [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) to perform configuration changes. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then log in. You won't see any `*`s or anything at all while entering your password. That is by design.

You can then remove `slim` via the command line, which will reconfigure your other display manager to work again (since you didn't actually remove it). This command will do that:

```
sudo apt-get remove slim
```

Or you can reconfigure your other display manager (in this case, `gdm`) to be the default, while keeping `slim` installed:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

(Thanks to [Anwar Shah](https://askubuntu.com/users/61218/anwar-shah) for pointing this out.)

As another alternative, which does not require rebooting, you can manually stop `slim` and start your other display manager (presumably `gdm` on this system). `slim` may well be stopped already, but issuing the `stop` command will then simply fail, and will not be harmful.

```
sudo stop slim
sudo start gdm
```

On later systems, you may have `lightdm` instead of `gdm` as the default display manager. Then you'd use `sudo start lightdm` instead. Similarly, on KDE, you may have `kdm`, so you'd use `sudo start kdm` instead.

You've asked how to revert to `gdm`. If you want to try to fix `slim` so it works properly, you might want to post another, separate question about that.

Finally, a note on terminology: these are [display managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_manager), *not* [window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager).